# android webservice mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services, tomcat

im starting in a second level of android programation and i want to get some advice and answer about first steps to do my applicaction.

My application needs to put some information in DB (mysql) from the terminal and any other terminal can get these consulting the DB... so i understand i need a BD (mysql) and a webservice to offer the procedures to insert and get data from BD.

I already code the android program and now i need only to upload the information to the BD.

There are my questions for anyone who have some experience and maybe can advice me.

1. i need a BD like mysql (it's ok??)
2. to test i installed tomcat 7.0 (it's ok??)
3. what more i need to do this? i want to do in java, so i need some libraries? other programas? im really lost

I know i ask for alotof things... but if someone know about some tutorial that i can follow to learn, i apreciate it

thank so much!

Comment: BD?? Your sure you didn't mistype DB?

Comment: course, DB (i think in spanish xD) sorry

Answer (score 1):

In java you can find  a lot of libraries which  can give a solution.I also tried this by using libraries "Ksop" and "json" 
You can check [Here](http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html) and [Here](http://android-devblog.blogspot.in/2010/06/soap-on-android.html).Think this will help you.

Comment: welcome and do't forgot to mark the answer as helpfull if it really help you